# How to move files between two VMs using gcloud?

Tags: gcloud

I have tried using `scp` provided by [gcloud](/questions/tagged/gcloud), however, that produces an error:

```sh
gcloud compute scp github-action-runner-0001:/tmp/images.tar github-action-runner-0002:/tmp/images.tar
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) All sources must be local files when destination is remote.  Got sources: [github-action-runner-0001:/tmp/images.tar], destination: github-action-runner-0002:/tmp/images.tar
```

I am evaluating if there are alternative ways of copying files from one VM to another using `gcloud` utilities.

Obviously, copying files locally first would work, however, given the size of the files this would not work reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have two Compute Engine virtual machines: VM-A and VM-B.

1. SSH login to VM-A.
2. Use the **gcloud compute scp** command to copy files to/from VM-B.

By logging into VM-A, it becomes the local system and VM-B becomes the remote system.

Note: Your question does not specify what **github-action-runner-0001** is. I m assuming that it is the name of a Compute Engine VM. If it is not, then complete step #1 and then copy the files from **github-action-runner-0001** to VM-A and then copy the files from VM-A to VM-B using step 2.

Comment: Thanks John. The goal was to achieve this without needing to SSH into machine. That being said, this is a great suggestion. For what it is worth, I ended up sharing persistent disks between VMs.

Comment: Some SSH tools have an **rcp** (remote copy) command which would accomplish your goal. However, the Google Cloud CLI does not offer that feature.